# Can I reset CFBundleShortVersionString

Tags: ios, app-store

I started using an incremental number for my CFBundleShortVersionString for each new build (ex. 1->2->3->4) and now I am at 24.0. Can i reset this back to use a different versioning system like 1.0.24?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not upload your app already, you can always modify the CFBundleShortVersionString in the project settings > General > Version or by changing the the Bundle Version tag in the Info.plist file directly via XCode/Text Editor of your choice.

If you uploaded it to the App Store, i'm not 100% certain what happens but i remember being able to update the version in App Store Connect, too.

EDIT: I'll refer here to rmaddy answer concerning the behavior of semver if already published your app.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides the document [Technical Note TN2420 - Version Numbers and Build Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2420/_index.html).

The section [Version number and build number checklist](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2420/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016603-CH1-VERSION_NUMBER_AND_BUILD_NUMBER_CHECKLIST) states the following:

> Here are some things you can check when submitting a new build to the App Store. Making sure you have your version number and build number set properly will help you by avoiding having your app automatically rejected for having them improperly configured.
>
> 1. For each new version of your app, you need to invent a new version number. This number should be a greater value than the last Version Number that you used. Though you may provide many builds for any particular release of your App, you only need to use one new Version Number for each new release of your App.
> 2. You cannot re-use version numbers.
> 3. For every new build you submit, you will need to invent a new build number whose value is greater than the last build number you used (for that same version). For iOS apps, you may re-use build numbers when submitting different versions. For macOS apps, you must chose a new build number for every submission that is unique and has never been used before in any submission you have provided to the App Store (including build numbers used in previous versions of your app).
> 4. For iOS apps you can re-use build numbers in different release trains, but you cannot re-use build numbers within the same release train. For macOS apps, you cannot re-use build numbers in any release train.

The first paragraph is the most important to your question.

> For each new version of your app, you need to invent a new version number. This number should be a greater value than the last Version Number that you used.

The use of the word *"should"* is the most interesting here. This implies that while you should make your version number greater, you don't have to. As I read this, you should be able to go from version 24.0 to 1.0.24. But the second paragraph is important. If you have already used 2.0 then you can never go from your new 1.0.x to 2.0.